# airflow time zone change from UTC to CET

Tags: python, airflow

I want to run a dag in airflow whose execution date should be in CET but by default AIRFLOW runs on UTC .. and so if I want to use the value of of TS or EXECUTION_DATE in a variable... it is showing current time in UTC.. How can I get execution_date in CET time zone

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please show us some code, so that we can help.

Answer (score 2):

With the current versions of Airflow (1.10.x) they require the module, [pendulum](http://pendulum.eustace.io), because there's some limited support for [timezone aware scheduling](https://airflow.apache.org/timezone.html).

The macro values of `TS` and `EXECUTION_DATE` are (iirc) set to the Airflow system's UTC timezone because that's what Airflow converts everything to when persisting to the DB and displaying the UI. You might have expected that changing this in the config:

```
[core]
default_timezone = utc
```

could affect this, but it seems to only affect the understanding of Naive date times (e.g. if you set a DAG start_date to `Datetime(2018,12,25)` it will be assumed to be in the `default_timezone`)

You can convert `execution_date` in a DAG within a PythonOperator like this:

```
import pendulum

desired_tz = pendulum.timezone("Europe/Amsterdam")
desired_tz.convert(execution_date)
```

Because `execution_date` will already know it's in UTC the conversion should be accurate. Note that this doesn't assign it to anything nor change the `execution_date`.

Here's what happens if you work with local times (unknown timezone):

```
>>> import pendulum
>>> dtz=pendulum.timezone("Europe/Amsterdam")
>>> dtz
Timezone('Europe/Amsterdam')
>>> import datetime
>>> d=datetime.datetime.now()
>>> d
datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 17, 17, 36, 5, 435666)
>>> dtz.convert(d)  # Notice unchanged
datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 17, 17, 36, 5, 435666, tzinfo=Timezone('Europe/Amsterdam'))
>>> d
datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 17, 17, 36, 5, 435666)
>>> dtz.convert(pendulum.timezone("UTC").convert(d))  # Notice changed
datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 17, 18, 36, 5, 435666, fold=1, tzinfo=Timezone('Europe/Amsterdam'))
>>> d  # Notice change not assigned
datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 17, 17, 36, 5, 435666)
```

So… I hope that helps, because CET has a variable offset from UTC IIRC.

Comment: Can you show full code of PythonOperator where you are converting execution_date to another time zone?

Comment: @RomanKazakov assuming you already know how to get execution_date in your PythonOperator, simply apply the 3 lines that start with `import pendulum` and end with `convert(execution_date)`. Bear in mind you want to assign the return value of the convert method to something. I don't think it changes the parameter passed to it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know a way how to override/patch TaskInstance class to override initialization of ds and other template variables. Now they are strictly converted to UTC during class initialization

Answer (score 2):

`execution_date` is a [Pendulum](https://pendulum.eustace.io/) object.

You can convert the UTC time using [`in_timezone()`](https://pendulum.eustace.io/docs/#switching-timezones) method.

An example code:

```py
from datetime import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator

dag = DAG(
    dag_id="example",
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=datetime(year=1993, month=8, day=31)
)

with dag:
    echo_op = BashOperator(
        task_id="exec_date_as_cst",
        bash_command="echo {{ execution_date.in_timezone('CET') }}"
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a cool library called arrow that you can use to convert time from one time zone to another

```
>>> import arrow
>>> utc = arrow.utcnow()
>>> utc
<Arrow [2018-12-15T20:50:33.156717+00:00]>
>>> local = utc.to('CET')
>>> local
<Arrow [2018-12-15T21:50:33.156717+01:00]>
```

A way with only built-in libraries

```
>>> import dateutil.parser
>>> import timedelta
>>> ts = "201812160105"
>>> date = dateutil.parser.parse(ts)
datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 16, 1, 5)
>>> cet_ts = ts + timedelta(hours=1) # UTC + 1 hour = CET
datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 16, 2, 5)
```

and if you want it back in the iso format

```
>>> cet_ts.isoformat()
'2018-12-16T02:05:00'
```

Edit:

To convert a string in the ISO 8601 format you can use the following command

```
>>> ts = '2018-12-15T21:10:00+00:00'
>>> arrow.get(ts)
<Arrow [2018-12-15T21:10:00+00:00]>
```

and to convert the date from UTC to CET simply run

```
>>> utc.to('CET')
<Arrow [2018-12-15T22:10:00+01:00]>
```

Comment: actually I want to use ts in CET. So I want to add 1 hour to ts since ts is in UTC.
So I was trying:
dt1 = datetime.strptime( '{{ ts }}',"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+%HH:%MM")
dt = dt1 + timedelta(hours=1)
but I am getting error: redefinition of group name 'H' as group 7; was group 4

Comment: As you can see after using "utc.to('CET')"  hour changed from 20:50 to 21:50. The thing you would need to do first is to convert the object. If it's a datetime object you can use **arrow.Arrow.strptime(y.isoformat(), '%H:%M:%S')** command. If it does not work could you please let me know what is the type of the object you are trying to convert

Comment: I am trying to convert  {{ ts }} which is a macro object in airflow.It is in isoformat().
 example of {{ ts }} : 2018-12-15T21:10:00+00:00

Comment: Ok, so a good idea would be to convert it into a datetime object. You can do that with **dateutil.parser.parse(ts)** but first, you need to **import dateutil**

Comment: dateutil.parser.parse() is not able to parse. getting error as : unknown string

Comment: One second. You gave me a format of **ts** so ill add an edit section to my answer with working code

Comment: Thanks for your time and help but actually if I pass a hardcoded string manually then its working.  But when I am trying to work with dynamic value  i.e {{ ts }} which is a macro object , then its not working anymore

Comment: Ok, could you add **import pdb; pdb.set_trace()** one line over the place where the program crashes, run it and type "type(ts)" and tell me what is the output

Comment: its not working :(  . import pdb; and pdb.set_trace() are not working.

Comment: DATE_TRIM_MACRO =  "{{ ts.replace('-','').replace('T','').replace(':','')[:11] }}"
above line works fine and returns 20181216010

Comment: you can read how to use python debugger [here][1]. Then use it to check the value and type of variable "ts". If I don't know this two things I can't help you

    [1] [https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-python-debugger]

Comment: DATE_TRIM_MACRO =  "{{ ts.replace('-','').replace('T','').replace(':','')[:11] }}"
above line works fine and returns 20181216010
But if Write DATE_TRIM_MACRO =  "{{ ts.replace('-','').replace('T','').replace(':','')[:12] }}"
which returns 201812160105  and then 

dt = datetime.strptime(DATE_TRIM_MACRO,"%Y%m%d%H%M%S") ..this line  gives error: format %Y%m%d%H%M%S not supported

Comment: whereas if i write datetime.strptime("201812160105 ","%Y%m%d%H%M%S")..it works fine

Comment: If at any point you get the **ts** variable in the format '2018-12-15T21:10:00+00:00' as have given me as an example before it should work with **var = arrow.get(ts)**. If you need to get it back just use **var.datetime**

Comment: is there any other way except using  arrow because I am not able to install arrow right now due to permission issues.

Comment: Ow, you should have said earlier. Sure there is

Comment: I've added a way to do it with only build in libraries to my answer

Comment: exactly thats what I am trying to say.. I have used this way earlier also... when ever we are taking any hardcoded values like ts= "123456789...."... rest of the lines are working fine...but
this macro object is the problem... i.e  {{ ts }}    .This is not a local variable. this is a macro object which means the execution date in isoformat() .. I am not able to play with this macro object

Comment: I found out a different solution and its working now finally. thank you for the effort :)

Answer (score 0):

```
EXEC_DATE = "{{ (execution_date + macros.timedelta(hours=1)).strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M')}}"
```

This will add one hour to the  {{ ts }} and will work like CET :)

Comment: Until… daylight savings changes the offset between UTC and CET.